# The server encountered an error and could not complete your request

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to deploy on App Engine Google a small App. The app goes well on localhost and deploy well, but I have an error message on production. **The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.**

**Errors**

W 2014-04-05 10:12:02.177 EXCEPTION java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-f5cd6230c17e8858(Request.java) at java.lang.ClassLoade

E 2014-04-05 10:12:02.177 javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable javax.servlet.UnavailableException at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79) at org.

W 2014-04-05 10:12:02.178 Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@ec911f{/,/base/data/home/apps/s~pattheboldandjuju/1.37489685

C 2014-04-05 10:12:02.180 Uncaught exception from servlet javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Initialization failed. at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMa

My code is quite simple :

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class>guestbook.GuestbookServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Guestbook</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping> 
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>guestbook.jsp</welcome-file> 
    </welcome-file-list>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter> 
    <filter-mapping>            
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**guestbook.jsp**

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %> <%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="guestbook.Message" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html> 
    <head>
        <title>Livre d'or</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Vous avez aimé mon site ? Dites-le dans le Datastore !</h1> 
        <form action="/post" method="post">
            <p>
            <label>Votre nom : <input type="text" name="name" /></label>
            </p> 
            <p>
                <label>Votre message :<br />
                <textarea name="message" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;"></textarea></label>
            </p> 
            <p>
                <input type="submit" /> 
            </p>
            </form>
        <h1>Ils ont aimé :</h1> 
        <%
        List<Message> messages = (List<Message>) request.getAttribute("messages");
        for (Message message : messages) { 
        %>
        <p>
            <strong><%= message.getName() %></strong> a écrit :<br /> <%= message.getMessage() %>
        </p> 
        <%}%> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**GuestbookServlet.java**

```
package guestbook;

import static com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService.ofy;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory;
import com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyService;

@SuppressWarnings( "serial" )
public class GuestbookServlet extends HttpServlet {

    // Enregistrement de la classe persistable auprès d'Objectify
    static {
        ObjectifyService.register( Message.class );
    }

    public void doGet( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp ) {
        try {
            // Requête Objectify
            List<Message> messages = ofy().load().type( Message.class ).ancestor( KeyFactory.createKey( "LivreOr", "livreOr" ) ).order( "-date" ).limit( 5 ).list();
            req.setAttribute( "messages", messages );
            this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher( "/WEB-INF/guestbook.jsp" ).forward( req, resp );
        } catch ( ServletException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void doPost( HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp ) {
        try {
            // Création de l'objet
            Message message = new Message( req.getParameter( "name" ), req.getParameter( "message" ) );

            // Enregistrement de l'objet dans le Datastore avec Objectify
            ofy().save().entity( message ).now();
            resp.sendRedirect( "/" );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**appengine-web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">

  <application>pattheboldandjuju</application>
  <version>1</version>

  <!--
    Allows App Engine to send multiple requests to one instance in parallel:
  -->
  <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>

  <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
  <system-properties>
    <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" value="WEB-INF/logging.properties"/>
  </system-properties>

  <!--
    HTTP Sessions are disabled by default. To enable HTTP sessions specify:

      <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>

    It's possible to reduce request latency by configuring your application to
    asynchronously write HTTP session data to the datastore:

      <async-session-persistence enabled="true" />

    With this feature enabled, there is a very small chance your app will see
    stale session data. For details, see
    http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Enabling_Sessions
  -->

</appengine-web-app>
```

Any idea to deal with this problem ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resources inside `/WEB-INF` are used for configuration and are not public viewable, so you can not forward a request to `/WEB-INF/guestbook.jsp`.

Try moving `guestbook.jsp` to a public accessible location.

Comment: I am not sure that it is the solution because I have the same error if I only put :         resp.setContentType( "text/plain" );
        resp.getWriter().println( "Hello, world" ); Of course I tried to implement guestbook.jsp somewhere else as you suggested with no success.